Slick grid collapse and expand icons
I know I am being dense, but I cannot figure out how to move to the SVG images.
I do not see expanded or collapsed icons in my grid; however, the functionality works.
I am using the following version of SlickGrid - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slickgrid@5.8.1/dist/
I had this code
 .toggle.expand {
    background: url(http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/images/expand.gif) no-repeat center center;
  }

  .toggle.collapse {
    background: url(http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/images/collapse.gif) no-repeat center center;
  }

and changed it to this
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slickgrid@5.8.1/dist/styles/css/slick.grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slickgrid@5.8.1/dist/styles/css/slick-default-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slickgrid@5.8.1/dist/styles/css/slick-icons.css" type="text/css"/> // added this line
.toggle.expand {
    --alpine-group-expanded-icon-svg: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg viewBox="0 0 24 24" display="inline-block" height="1em" width="1em" vertical-align="text-bottom" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" %3E%3Cpath fill="currentColor" d="M19,19V5H5V19H19M19,3A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19V5C3,3.89 3.9,3 5,3H19M17,11V13H7V11H17Z"/%3E%3C/svg%3E');
    -webkit-mask: var(--alpine-group-expanded-icon-svg) no-repeat;
    mask: var(--alpine-group-expanded-icon-svg) no-repeat;
    mask-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%
}

.toggle.collapse {
    --alpine-group-collapsed-icon-svg: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg viewBox="0 0 24 24" display="inline-block" height="1em" width="1em" vertical-align="text-bottom" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" %3E%3Cpath fill="currentColor" d="M19,19V5H5V19H19M19,3A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19V5C3,3.89 3.9,3 5,3H19M11,7H13V11H17V13H13V17H11V13H7V11H11V7Z"/%3E%3C/svg%3E');
    -webkit-mask: var(--alpine-group-collapsed-icon-svg) no-repeat;
    mask: var(--alpine-group-collapsed-icon-svg) no-repeat;
    mask-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%
}

any help is appreciated.  I have tried many things and have yet to be successful.

if you're using custom Formatters, then just use the new SlickGrid Icons
